# Регулярное выражение в javascript, количество цифр

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть скрипт, для правильной записи суммы с копейками(после точки только две цифры). Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы до точки было только 5 цифр?

```
 var flag = false;
    $('.sum_polis').on({
        input: function(e){
            var re =/^\d+\.?(\d{1,2})?$/ig,
                cVal = $.trim($(this).val());
            var cVal = $.trim($(this).val());
            $(this).val(cVal.replace(/,/g, '.'));
            if(flag){
                var cut = cVal.match(/^\d+\.?(\d{1,2})?/ig),
                    clearVal =  cut !== null ? cut : '';
                $(this).val(clearVal);
                return false;
            }
            if(!re.test(cVal)){
                $(this).val(cVal.substr(0,cVal.length-1));
            }
        },
        paste: function(){
            flag = true;
        },
        blur: function(){
            var cVal = $.trim($(this).val());
            if(/\.$/.test(cVal)){
                $(this).val(cVal.substr(0,cVal.length-1));
            }
        }
    });
```

Пробовал вот в этой регулярке поменять значение var re =/^\d+.?(\d{1,2})?$/ig, на var re =/^\d{0,5}.?(\d{1,2})?$/ig, не помогает. Он просто не дает записывать больше 5 цифр. Как тут правильно написать регулярку? Хотелось бы так, чтобы до точки было не больше 5 цифр и можно было поставить точку, и дописать еще 2 цифры.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярка будет выглядеть так `^\d{0,5}(\.\d{0,2})?$`. Обратите внимание `12345.` будет валидными значениями в этой регулярке. Это нужно именно для того чтоб у пользователя была возможность поставить точку.

Так как во время ввода текста возникает ситуация `верно -> неверно -> верно` (например `123 -> 123. -> 123.4`), вам прийдётся проверить введённые данные еще раз на случай если пользователь остановился на точке и перевёл фокус ввода на другое поле. В этом случае нужно будет или убрать точку или дописать нули. На ваш вкус.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал по своему, но ваш ответ помог!